# displaying mapbox maptiles in android using osmdroid

Tags: android, json, osmdroid, mapbox

I have tried to retrieve map tiles from mapbox using osmdroid just like how modestmaps.js do( ex: http://tristen.ca/mm-examples/basic-controls.html) i have tried in all possible ways no use, can any one pls guide me how to write my own OnlineTIleSourceBase that can retrieve tiles from mapbox.
Thanx in advance.

---

Ok i got it!! but can some one pls guide me how to display all markers to fit screen. I have tried using BoundingBoxE6 but i am getting a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

MapBox is currently working on a full Android SDK that will be released within the next few months. Please check [the blog](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/) for more updates.